Why my tomcat do not open when i run spring boot project?
When i run my first spring boot project. Tomcat does not run
This is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <relativePath/<!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bach</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hello-spring-boot</name>
    <description>First simple project with spring-boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>



I added spring-boot-starter-web into dependencies but when i run i didn't receive any messages about tomcat server

I also added spring boot maven plugin and spring boot starter parent

Don't do this, just start at https://start.spring.io/ or let IDE create your maven spring boot project.

Two issues in you POM.

Scope for spring-boot-starter-web: The spring-boot-starter-web dependency should not have the scope set to test. This dependency is necessary for running your Spring Boot application and embedding Tomcat. Instead add the test scope to the spring-boot-starter-test dependency.

Duplicate spring-web Dependency: The spring-web dependency is already included in spring-boot-starter-web, so you can remove it.


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

